# Using get() to identify a string within a returned list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a workflow I'm trying to clean up that has worked for someone else in the past, but when I run it I get the error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

I have the following code:

```
results = []
move_forward = 0

def testing(move_forward):
  if move_forward == 0:
    j = "123"
    hta = 0.93
    htac = 0.90
    hti = 2
    htri = 2
    return ("value_a, %s, value_b: %f, value_c: %f, value_d: %d, value_e: %d" % (j, hta, htac, hti, htri))
  else:
    return ("move_forward returned a non-zero return code")

results.append(testing(move_forward))

if "move_forward returned a non-zero return code" in results[-1].get():
    print("Code failed....exiting")
else:
  print("Code complete....exiting")
```

I am currently running this on python 3.6

Later code also uses get(), for example:

```
p_t = float(results[-1].get().split(',')[2].split(':')[1])
```

and

```
for i in range(0, len(results)):
    print("i: %d result: %s" % (i, results[i].get()))
```

I'm anticipating similar errors once I get there...

From my understanding the error is because I've got a list with strings rather than a dict. Is there a way to get results to register as a dict or for .get() to work on results? Or is there another way to do this without .get()?

Comment: Even if you have a dict, `.get()` still expects an argument

Comment: I am not sure if you even need a get here, results[-1].get()

Comment: I am aware that .get() expects an argument, that will give the error: TypeError: get expected at least 1 arguments, got 0. Currently the code doesn't register that error due to the current one.

Comment: Like the error says the `str` built in doesnt have a get method. Are you getting this mixed up with pandas series which would support `Series.str.get`

Comment: The original code does not utilize pandas. I am also not sure why .get() was used here. My goal is to get the code running.

Comment: Well it might be eaiser to show the original code or at least explain what your trying to do cause you could just write `if "move_forward returned a non-zero return code" in results[-1]` and it would be True if the string was contained in the last element of your results list

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm the suggestion that .get() is not needed. The code runs as intended with .get() removed. Thanks!